# How to put in TWIG a condition, if the user does not have the role?

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

In my TWIG file for Drupal 8, I have this code :

```
  {% if 'marchand_premium' in user.getroles  %}
     test ...
  {% endif %}
```

This will display the text if the user has the role of marchand_premium

I would like the opposite.

How to put in TWIG a condition, if the user does not have the role marchand_premium ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`not` operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#math) :

```
{% if 1 not in [1, 2, 3] %}

{# is equivalent to #} 
{% if not (1 in [1, 2, 3]) %}
```

So you can do this :

```
{% if 'marchand_premium' not in user.getroles  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_granted like that:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') == false %}
 {% endif %}
```

Or:

```
{% if not is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: "is_granted" function is not available in drupal 8